# Working with specific layers within raster brick in r

Tags: r, raster

This may be a simple question.
I have a raster brick with 23 layers in it. I want to create an average image of layer 12 to layer 17. I can do this in many ways on other software. but what I didnt understand is I can plot layer 12 to 17 by simply writing

```
plot(x,12:17)
```

but I cant calculate average by

```
s<-sum(x,12:17)
a<-s/6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `subset` on your `RasterStack` and then calculate the mean.

```
x_sub <- subset(x, 12:17)
mean_raster <- mean(x_sub, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Comment: What if you need to modify the subset layer(s)? I'm getting the error `could not find function "subset<-"`